# Clearing stored usernames and passwords for webview Basic4Android

Tags: basic4android

How do you clear usernames and passwords for a webview?

Tried:

`reflect.RunMethod2("clearCache","True","java.lang.boolean")`

`reflect.RunMethod("clearFormData")`

They still pop-up.

Thanks,
-Sean

Comment: Not sure if it will solve your issue but it is better to write: `reflect.RunMethod2("clearCache",True,"java.lang.boolean")`

Answer (score 0):

This is Java code that solves what you want. Maybe can be useful to you if you find basic4android equivalent:

```
Preference myPref = findPreference("myPref");
myPref.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
        MyActivity.mWebView.clearCache(true);
        return false;
    }
});
```